# How to block-diagonalize a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have encountered the fact on wikipedia that every skew-symmetric matrix can be block-diagonalized, where the matrix is in the form indicated by the following picture. I was wondering if there is a proof for such a statement through diagonalizing $M^2$, since $M^2$ is self-adjoint and can be diagonalized into orthonormal basis by spectral theorem.[image]

Comment: Evidently you are working over $\mathbb R$... yes, you can use the eigenspaces of $M^2$ to show this result but it takes some work.  See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638769/the-orthogonal-standard-form-of-antisymmetric-matrix/  Note: using polar decomposition $M=VP$ for symmetric positive (semi)definite $P$ then $M^2 = -M^TM= -P^2$ where $-P^2$ has the same eigenvectors as $P$.