$O$ orthogonal with $\det(O)=-1$ implies $||\Omega - O \Omega O^{T}|| = 2 $?
Let $O\in \mathrm{O}(2n)$ be an orthogonal matrix. Let $\Omega$ be the matrix $\Omega:=
\bigoplus^n_{i=1} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
-1 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}.$
Is it true that:
$\det(O)=-1$ implies $||\Omega - O \Omega O^{T}|| = 2 $ ?
Here $||\cdot||$ denotes the operator norm (largest singular value of the matrix).

why would you think so? Where does this problem come from? What have you already tried?

Numerically it seems true.
It comes from a formula from quantum physics that I'm trying to prove.

if $n = 1$, this is true, but for $n=2$ I think this is false

why? Can you please show a counter-example?

Ok, no, my computations also say that it should be true, and moreover, it is equivalent to prove that $\Omega + O\Omega O^T$ is singular

The link to the pdf is broken. Nonetheless I think this should be proved using reflections

Thank you so much for your help. I reached the same conclusion and I also agree that it reduces to show that $\Omega+O\Omega O^{T}$ is singular. I think that showing that such matrix follows from Corollary 2.4.(b) of this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379510001266?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=881ba9cfafb6aca9. Thus, I think that the problem should be solved. I'm trying to understand if there is an elementary proof!

The proof in the paper that you have mentioned is already quite elementary. However, as it is intended for a more general statement, you may strip it down and modify it to a shorter proof in your case.
Here is the idea. Let $J=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$. For any $r>1$, define $W_r=J\oplus rJ\oplus r^2 J\oplus\cdots\oplus r^{n-1}J$. We will show that
$$
\max\limits_{U\in O(2n),\,\det U=-1}\det(W_r+U\Omega U^T)\le\left(\prod_{0\le k\le n-2}(r^k+1)^2\right)(r^{n-1}-1)^2.\tag{1}
$$
(Note that the LHS is nonnegative because it is the determinant of a skew-symmetric matrix.) Once this is shown, by letting $r\to1^+$, we obtain $\det(\Omega+O\Omega O^T)=0$. Hence $O\Omega O^Tx=-\Omega x$ for some unit vector $x$ and
$$
2=\|\Omega\|+\|O\Omega O^T\|
\ge\|\Omega-O\Omega O^T\|
\ge\|(\Omega-O\Omega O^T)x\|
=\|2\Omega x\|=2.
$$
It remains to prove $(1)$. Fix $r>0$ and let $U\in O(2n)\setminus SO(2n)$ be a global maximiser of $\det(W_r+U\Omega U^T)$. Clearly $(1)$ holds when $\det(W_r+U\Omega U^T)=0$. Now suppose that $C=W_r+U\Omega U^T$ is invertible. Let $B=U\Omega U^T$. Then $t=0$ is a global maximiser of $f(t)=\det(W_r+e^{tK}Be^{-tK})$ for every skew-symmetric matrix $K$. Therefore, by Jacobi's formula, we have
$$
0=f'(t)=\det(C)\operatorname{tr}(C^{-1}[K,B])
=\det(C)\operatorname{tr}([B,C^{-1}]K)
$$
for all skew-symmetric matrices $K$. In particular, this is true when $K=[B,C^{-1}]$ (the commutator is skew-symmetric because both $B$ and $C$ are skew-symmetric). Therefore $[B,C^{-1}]=0$ and $B$ commutes with $C$. In turn, $U\Omega U^T(=B)$ commutes with $W_r\,(=C-B)$. Hence $U\Omega U^T
$ must be in the form of
$$
\pm J\oplus\pm J\oplus\cdots\oplus\pm J,\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\det(W_r+U\Omega U^T)
=(1\pm 1)^2(r\pm 1)^2(r^2\pm 1)^2\cdots(r^{n-1}\pm1)^2.\tag{3}
$$
However, as $\operatorname{pf}(U^T\Omega U)=\det(U)\operatorname{pf}(\Omega)=-1$, the number of copies of $-J$ on the RHS of $(2)$ must be odd. Therefore at least one plus-or-minus symbol on the RHS of $(3)$ is negative. Thus $(1)$ follows.

Edit. Exodd suggests skippping the continuity argument and the use of Pfaffian. I will skip the former but retain the latter.
The idea is to consider the maximisation of $\det(\Omega+U\Omega U^T)$ directly. As in the above, at a global maximum $U\Omega U^T$ must commute with $\Omega$. Since both matrices are real and normal, they can be simultaneously orthogonally block-diagonalised into $2\times 2$ sub-blocks. So, we may assume that $U\Omega U^T$ is a direct sum of copies of $\pm J$. This direct sum must contain at least one copy of $-J$, otherwise we will have $U\Omega U^T=\Omega$, but this is impossible because
$$
\operatorname{pf}(U\Omega U^T)=\det(U)\operatorname{pf}(\Omega)=-1\ne1=\operatorname{pf}(\Omega).
$$
Therefore $U\Omega U^T$ must contain $-J$ as a diagonal sub-block. Hence $\det(\Omega+U\Omega U^T)=0$. In turn, $\det(\Omega+O\Omega O^T)=0$ too.

you gave an upper bound to the determinant. Why it cannot be negative?

@Exodd The determinant of a real skew-symmetric matrix is always nonnegative.

I think $r$ can be skipped and we can work directly with $W_1$. We just need to suppose by absurd that $C$ is invertible and then prove that it is not

Also, once we get $\Omega = U\Omega U^T$ I think that one can reach an absurd without the Pfaffian. Maybe showing that the two matrices are not in the same connected component?

yes, but you can reach that conclusion by absurd: since they commute and $C$ is invertible, then $U\Omega U^T$ cannot have any $-J$, so it is equal to $\Omega$. At this point, $U\Omega = \Omega U$ so they commute and $U$ must also be a direct sum of $\pm J$, but its determinant is $-1$, contradiction.

Yes, in fact I'm working by absurd! The idea is: set $r=1$ from the start, assume by absurd that $C$ is invertible, follow all the steps to find that $U\Omega U^T$ and $\Omega$ commute, but from $C = \Omega + U\Omega U^T$, since $C$ is invertible, then $U\Omega U^T$ cannot have $-J$ inside, thus $\Omega = U\Omega U^T$ and $\Omega U = U \Omega$, so $U$ is also composed only by $\pm J$, that is a contradiction since $\det(U) = -1$

@Exodd Thanks. Done (but I keep the Pfaffian).

Thanks a lot both!

summary:  my original proof is below, though the argument boils down to
(1) $\det\big(\Omega Q +Q\Omega\big) \leq 0$
either because (a) $\big(\Omega Q +Q\Omega\big)= \big(\Omega + Q\Omega Q^T\big)Q$, a skew-symmetric matrix times an orientation reversing orthogonal matrix or (b) those familiar with examining degrees of maps on the sphere, i.e. $f, g: S^{2n-1}\longrightarrow S^{2n-1}$, routinely check $\frac{\tau \cdot f(x) + (1-\tau)\cdot g(x)}{\Vert \tau\cdot f(x) + (1-\tau)\cdot g(x)\Vert}$ shows the degree is constant so long as nothing in the numerator is mapped to zero when $\tau =\frac{1}{2}$-- this generated my original argument
(2) $\det\big(\Omega Q +Q\Omega\big) \geq 0$
since $\Omega\big(\Omega Q +Q\Omega\big)\Omega^{-1} = \big(\Omega Q +Q\Omega\big)$ and $\Omega^2 = -I$, ref Nonnegativity of the determinant of a commuting matrix

with $J= \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1 \\  -1 &0 \end{bmatrix}$
$\Omega = I_n \otimes J =\begin{bmatrix}  J &\mathbf 0 &\dots &\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0&J &\dots &\mathbf 0\\  \vdots  &  \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ \mathbf 0&\mathbf 0&\dots &J\end{bmatrix}$  and $Q \in O_{2n}(\mathbb R) -SO_{2n}(\mathbb R)$, to prove OP's claim it suffices to show $\det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big) = 0$
(i.) Lemma: $\det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big) \leq 0$
$U_\tau:= (1-\tau)\cdot \Omega Q + \tau \cdot Q\Omega$,  for $\tau \in \big[0, \frac{1}{2}\big]$
$\det\big(U_0\big)= \det\big(\Omega\big)\cdot \det\big( Q\big)=-1$ and when $\tau \in \big(0, \frac{1}{2}\big)$, for any $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^{2n} - \big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$
$\big\Vert U_\tau\mathbf x\big \Vert_2 \geq (1-\tau)\big \Vert \Omega Q\mathbf x \big \Vert_2 - \tau \big \Vert Q\Omega\mathbf x\big \Vert_2 = (1-\tau)\big \Vert \mathbf x \big \Vert_2 - \tau \big \Vert \mathbf x\big \Vert_2=(1-2\tau)\big \Vert \mathbf x \big \Vert_2\gt 0$
$\implies \det\big(U_\tau \big)\lt 0$ when $\tau \lt \frac{1}{2}$ by Intermediate Value Theorem
$\implies \det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big) = 2^{2n}\cdot \det\big(U_{\frac{1}{2}} \big)\leq 0$ by taking limits
(ii.) Lemma: $\ker\Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\Big)$ is $\Omega$-invariant
The conjugation map $T:M_{2n}(\mathbb R) \longrightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ given by $T(X) = \Omega X \Omega^T$ is an involution with particularly nice fixed points
$T\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I \big) = -1\cdot\Omega\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)\Omega = -1\cdot\Big(- Q\Omega - \Omega Q -(-\lambda I)\Big)= \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)$
$\implies T\Big(\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I \big)^{k}\Big)=\Big(T\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I \big)\Big)^k = \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I \big)^{k}$
now if $\mathbf v \in \ker \Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\Big)$ then
$\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\big(\Omega \mathbf v\big) = T\Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\Big)\big(\Omega \mathbf v\big) =  \Omega\Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\Big)\mathbf v = \mathbf 0 $
$\implies \big(\Omega \mathbf v\big) \in \ker\Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda I\big)^{k}\Big) $
Conclusion
If $\det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big) \lt 0$ then $\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big)$ must have some negative eigenvalue $\lambda^*$ with algebraic multiplicity $r$ where $r$ is odd
$\implies \ker\Big( \big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega -\lambda^* I\big)^{r}\Big)$ is an odd ($r$-) dimensional $\Omega$-invariant subspace which is impossible (since $\Omega = -\Omega^T$ is invertible)
$\implies \det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big)=0$.

lemma i. is easier to prove: $\Omega + Q\Omega Q^T$ is skew-symmetric, so its determinant is always nonnegative

Very interesting proof.

@user1551 Thanks. I was pretty deep in the weeds when I came up with this; I agree with your simplifications. In effect the argument is $\det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big)\leq 0 $ (routine) but also $\det\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big)\geq 0 $ per https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261740/nonnegativity-of-the-determinant-of-a-commuting-matrix/ since $\big(\Omega Q + Q\Omega \big)$ commutes with $\Omega$. It is amusing to me that of the 5 proofs in that link (including 2 from me) my instinct was toward your approach.

So, there is no need to use reductio ad absurdum. Great!

Here is a simplification of user8675309’s brilliant algebraic proof, with major inputs from Exodd and user8675309. Let $S=\Omega O+O\Omega$ and $K=SO^T=\Omega+O\Omega O^T$. Then $S$ commutes with $\Omega$ [remark 1] (as $S\Omega=\Omega O\Omega-O=\Omega S$) and $K$ is skew-symmetric.
We claim that $\det(S)=0$. On one hand, as $S$ and $\Omega$ commute, if $S$ has any negative eigenvalue, the corresponding generalised eigenspace must be an invariant subspace of $\Omega$ [remark 2]. However, all invariant subspaces of $\Omega$ are even-dimensional — this can be proved using either that $\Omega$ is an invertible skew-symmetric matrix or that $\Omega^2=-I$. Therefore the multiplicity of each negative eigenvalue of $S$ must be even and in turn $\det(S)\ge0$. On the other hand, we also have $\det(S)=\det(KO)=\det(K)\det(O)\le0$. Therefore $\det(S)$ must be zero, $S$ is singular and so is $K=SO^T=\Omega+O\Omega O^T$. Thus $O\Omega O^Tx=-\Omega x$ for some unit vector $x$ and
$$
2=\|\Omega\|+\|O\Omega O^T\|
\ge\|\Omega-O\Omega O^T\|
\ge\|(\Omega-O\Omega O^T)x\|
=\|2\Omega x\|=2.\quad\square
$$

Remarks. More generally, let $A,B\in M_n(F)$ for some field $F$.

If $A$ commutes with $B^2$, the anti-commutator $AB+BA$ will commute with $B$.

If $A$ and $B$ commute and $f$ is a polynomial, then $\ker f(A)$ is an invariant subspace of $B$, because $f(A)v=0$ implies that $f(A)Bv=Bf(A)v=0$. If we take $f(x)=(x-\lambda)^n$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, this means every generalised eigenspace of $A$ is $B$-invariant. Note that this is different from the usual textbook statement about invariant subspaces for commuting matrices:

the usual statement: if $A$ and $B$ commute and $V$ is an invariant subspace of $A$, then $\color{red}{BV}$ is also $\color{red}{A}$-invariant;
our statement here: if $A$ and $B$ commute and $V$ is a generalised eigenspace of $A$, then $\color{red}{V}$ is also $\color{red}{B}$-invariant.




I have only seen the commuting techniques used for normal matrices. Does it work in general or S is normal?

@Exodd I am not sure what technique you are referring to. Please see the clarifications in my new edit.

Why $\det(K)\det(O)\le 0$? For assumptions we have $\det(O)=-1$,  and also $\det(K)\le 0$ because $K$ is skew-symmetric.. Thus it should be $\det(K)\det(O)\ge 0$, right?

@DantePerès No. The determinant of a real skew-symmetric matrix is always nonnegative, as it has not any nonzero real eigenvalue and its non-real eigenvalues occur in conjugate pairs.

Ups, sorry, you're right, I got confused! Thank you and great proof(s)!

This is only a partial answer, but here's a proof for the $n=1$ case; perhaps this can be generalized via induction?
We will prove
$$\|\Omega O - O\Omega\| = 2.$$
This is equivalent to the OPs problem, because the operator norm is invariant under right (or left) multiplication with an orthogonal matrix (here, $O$). It thus suffices to compute the eigenvalues of $(\Omega O - O\Omega)^\top (\Omega O - O\Omega)$, and prove that the square root of the largest eigenvalue is 2 (basic property of singular values).
We compute $(\Omega O - O\Omega)^\top (\Omega O - O\Omega)$ manually at first, which yields (using the fact that both $\Omega$ and $O$ are orthogonal)
$$(\Omega O - O\Omega)^\top (\Omega O - O\Omega) = 2I - A - A^\top,$$
where $A = O^\top\Omega^\top O\Omega$. Thus, it would suffice to show $A+A^\top = -2I$.
For n=1, using the representation $O = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and the fact that $-1 = \text{det}(O) = ad-bc$, I'll let you check that $A = -I$, which completes the proof.
Perhaps by explicitly writing down $O$ as above, a similar proof can be constructed for $n>1$?
